# Moving /var to fuse pooled fs

Tags: mount, fuse

There do seem to be several questions already about moving `/var` to another directory or another partition or device.  What I would like to do is move it to a fuse-pooled fs.

My goal:  To install Linux server onto a USB, and have a fuse fs to manage the mounted JBOD's.  But I would like to move `/var` to the storage pool because a lot of people warn against too many writes to the USB, thus shortening its life.  If I move `/var` to the attached `/storage` pool then the sticks life is greatly lenthened.

The problem is when i added a bind mount to my `/etc/fstab` pointing `/storage/var` to `/var`, the OS hung on reboot.  I had to go to recovery mode to reverse my changes.

Here was my `/etc/fstab` before I recovered it.

```
# SnapRAID Dsks
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-abc-part1  /mnt/data/disk1 ext4 defaults 0 2
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-def-part1  /mnt/data/disk2 ext4 defaults 0 2
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ghi-part1  /mnt/data/disk3 ext4 defaults 0 2
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-jkl-part1  /mnt/data/disk4 ext4 defaults 0 2

# Parity Disks
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-lmn-part1  /mnt/data/disk5 ext4 defaults 0 2


# MergerFS 
/mnt/data/* /storage fuse.mergerfs category.create=eplfs,defaults,allow_other,minfreespace=20G,fsname=mergerfsPool 0 00

# bind mount
/storage/var  /var   ext4    defaults    0 0
```

Is this impossible, or should I directly bind mount it to one disk directly instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of moving /var to the pool, a better solution would be to move /var to the tmpfs.  After reading [this](https://www.chrisnewland.com/using-linux-tmpfs-to-reduce-disk-writes-for-power-saving-and-longer-cf-lifespan-186) from Chris Newland, I am going to go with moving /var to tmpfs, and adding `noatime` to the root install drive.

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information. 
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>                   <dump>  <pass> 
proc            /proc           proc    defaults                      0       0 
/dev/sda1       /               ext2    noatime,errors=remount-ro     0       1 
tmpfs           /tmp            tmpfs   defaults,noatime              0       0 
tmpfs           /var/log        tmpfs   defaults,noatime              0       0 
tmpfs           /var/tmp        tmpfs   defaults,noatime              0       0 
tmpfs           /var/run        tmpfs   defaults,noatime              0       0 
tmpfs           /var/spool      tmpfs   defaults,noatime              0       0 
tmpfs           /var/lock       tmpfs   defaults,noatime              0       0 
tmpfs           /var/cache      tmpfs   defaults,noatime              0       0
```

I also followed up with additional configurations due to some programs complaining about not having a temp place to write to (also from Chris Newland's page)...

This ensures that apache2, postgresql, and debconf all operate correctly when `/var/log` and `/var/cache` are mounted on a tmpfs filesystem:

```
# Put these commands into /etc/init.d/make-tmpfs-dirs 

#!/bin/sh 
mkdir /var/cache/debconf 

mkdir /var/log/apache2 
chown root:adm /var/log/apache2 
chmod 750 /var/log/apache2 

mkdir /var/log/postgresql 
chown root:postgres /var/log/postgresql 
chmod 774 /var/log/postgresql 
exit 0
```

Now make that executable:

```
chmod u+x /etc/init.d/make-tmpfs-dirs
```

...link to the make-tmpfs-dirs script from the correct rc.d runlevel directory

```
cd /etc/rc2.d 
ln -s ../init.d/make-tmpfs-dirs S02make-tmpfs-dirs
```

Finally instead of getting rid of swap, I will [reconfigure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness) it to not be used until its absolutely necessary (when I am running out of memory):

To change the system swappiness value in ubuntu, open `/etc/sysctl.conf` as root. Then, change or add this line to the file:

```
vm.swappiness = 10
```